# Extract elements in multiple dictionaries to a list?

Tags: python

The raw sources:

```
data_type = {'Number': ['int','bool','float','complex'],
             'Literal':['str','None','bytes']}
data_struture = {'Sequence':['list', 'dict', 'tuple','bytearray'],
                 'Set': ['set', 'frozenset']}
.
.
.
and others
```

I want this:

`['int','bool','float','complex','str','None','bytes'...]`

How to do it smarter?

Here is my codes in too many lines of command:

#### 1. package them in a class

```
`class TableContent:
    data_type = {'Number': ['int','bool','float','complex'],
                 'Literal':['str','None','bytes']}
    data_struture = {'Sequence':['list', 'dict', 'tuple','bytearray'],
                     'Set': ['set', 'frozenset']}`

`>>> foo = TableContent`
```

#### 2.get foo' attributes by vars()

```
`>>> vars(foo)
mappingproxy({'__module__': '__main__', 'data_type': {'Number': ['int', 'bool', 'float', 'complex'], 'Literal': ['str', 'None', 'bytes']}, 'data_struture': {'Sequence': ['list', 'dict', 'tuple', 'bytearray'], 'Set': ['set', 'frozenset']}, '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'TableContent' objects>, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'TableContent' objects>, '__doc__': None})`
```

#### 3.change the mappingproxy to dict:

```
`>>>bar = dict(vars(foo))`
`>>>bar
['__main__', {'Number': ['int', 'bool', 'float', 'complex'], 'Literal': ['str', 'None', 'bytes']}, {'Sequence': ['list', 'dict', 'tuple', 'bytearray'], 'Set': ['set', 'frozenset']}, <attribute '__dict__' of 'TableContent' objects>, <attribute '__weakref__' of 'TableContent' objects>, None]`
```

#### 4. slice the qualified elements

```
>>>bar = bar[1:-3]
>>>bar
[{'Number': ['int', 'bool', 'float', 'complex'], 'Literal': ['str', 'None', 'bytes']}, {'Sequence': ['list', 'dict', 'tuple', 'bytearray'], 'Set': ['set', 'frozenset']}]
```

#### 5. get values from the dic list

```
>>>baz = [ i.values() for i in bar]
>>>baz
[dict_values([['int', 'bool', 'float', 'complex'], ['str', 'None', 'bytes']]), dict_values([['list', 'dict', 'tuple', 'bytearray'], ['set', 'frozenset']])]
```

#### 6. change view object to list

```
>>>zot = [list(i.values()) for i in bar]
>>>zot
>>>[[['int', 'bool', 'float', 'complex'], ['str', 'None', 'bytes']], [['list', 'dict', 'tuple', 'bytearray'], ['set', 'frozenset']]]
```

#### 7. change list to string

```
>>>str(zot)
"[[['int', 'bool', 'float', 'complex'], ['str', 'None', 'bytes']], [['list', 'dict', 'tuple', 'bytearray'], ['set', 'frozenset']]]"
```

#### 8. manipulate the string

```
>>>zot = zot.replace('[', '')
"'int', 'bool', 'float', 'complex'], 'str', 'None', 'bytes']], 'list', 'dict', 'tuple', 'bytearray'], 'set', 'frozenset']]]"
>>>zot = zot.replace(']', '')
"'int', 'bool', 'float', 'complex', 'str', 'None', 'bytes', 'list', 'dict', 'tuple', 'bytearray', 'set', 'frozenset'"
```

#### try to convert string to list

```
>>>zot.split()
["'int',", "'bool',", "'float',", "'complex',", "'str',", "'None',", "'bytes',", "'list',", "'dict',", "'tuple',", "'bytearray',", "'set',", "'frozenset'"]
```

#### call eval()

```
>>>eval(zot)
('int', 'bool', 'float', 'complex', 'str', 'None', 'bytes', 'list', 'dict', 'tuple', 'bytearray', 'set', 'frozenset')
```

#### 9. then a list attained

```
>>>list(eval(zot))
['int', 'bool', 'float', 'complex', 'str', 'None', 'bytes', 'list', 'dict', 'tuple', 'bytearray', 'set', 'frozenset']
```

Could do it smarter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension:

```
>>> [v for vals in {**data_type, **data_struture}.values() for v in vals]
['int', 'bool', 'float', 'complex', 'str', 'None', 'bytes', 'list', 'dict', 'tuple', 'bytearray', 'set', 'frozenset']
```